# CKEDITOR ajax posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor

I am trying to make an admin page using AJAX so when the client updates information in the CKEDITOR it doesn't have to take him to a new page. Getting data from input fields are easy enough using the .val() function, but because textareas are not updated on the fly, I can't use that same function. Heres as far as I got:

// this replaces all textarea tags into CKEDITORS

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
</script>
```

//this attempts to grab all data from inputs and textareas

```
$(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var newsTitle = $("#newsTitle").val();
            var editNews = CKEDITOR.instances.editNews.getData();
            var contactTitle = $("#contactTitle").val();
            var editContact = CKEDITOR.instances.editContact.getData();
            var linksTitle = $("#linksTitle").val();
            var editLinks = CKEDITOR.instances.editLinks.getData();

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "update.php",
                   data: 'newsTitle='+newsTitle+'&editNews='+editNews+'&contactTitle='+contactTitle+'&editContact='+editContact+'&linksTitle='+linksTitle+'&editLinks='+editLinks,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function(){
                        updated();
                    }

                 });    

            return false;
        });
    });
```

the getData() function seemed like it would work because I tested it with alerts and it was grabbing the data from the editors, but once I would try and update, it wouldn't work...

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This code replaces the textarea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

CKEDITOR.replace( 'TEXTAREA_ID', {
    extraPlugins : 'autogrow',
    removePlugins : 'resize',
    entities : false
});

</script>
```

In the JS file this is the code and I am using Jquery Validator Plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

$("#FormID").validate({
    submitHandler: function(){

        var ContentFromEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.TEXTAREA_ID.getData();

        var dataString = $("#FormID").serialize();

            dataString += '&ContentFromEditor='+ContentFromEditor;          


        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Yourfile.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            YOU WORK WITH THE RETURN HERE
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ 
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
     });

   return false;

    }
});

});
```

This is the line that most of the time creates the error:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.TEXTAREA_ID.getData();
```

After the instances always comes the ID of the textarea.

I have my own config.js that you can get from the ckeditor website or from the examples.

Answer (score 2):

Tage a look at the CKEditor function/adaptor for jQuery

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/jQuery_Adapter

> Because setting and retrieving the editor data is a common operation, the jQuery Adapter also provides the dedicated val() method:

```
// Get the editor data.
var data = $( 'textarea.editor' ).val();
// Set the editor data.
$( 'textarea.editor' ).val( 'my new content' );
```

Comment: I just tried the adapter and the val() method does give me the right code in alerts, but it still refuses to post the data.

Comment: It might still be some function/object of some kind, try doing `$('/...').val().toString()` to return the context that `alert` showed

Answer (score 1):

With this code, my problems were solved.
I updated the field running ckeditor to be seen in serialize.

```
$('#form').find('.class').each(function(index) {
    $(this).val(CKEDITOR.instances[$(this).attr('id')].getData());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I used  .find('textarea').each(function(index) {
                        $(this).val(CKEDITOR.instances[$(this).attr('id')].getData());
                    });